# With expressJS, does res and req pass through to functions?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I'm using `CoffeeScript`, just a heads up:

```
searchResults = (err, data)->
  res.write 'hello'
  console.log data
  console.log 'here'
  return


exports.search = (req, res) ->
  res.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  location = req.param 'location'
  item = req.param 'item'

  geoC = googlemaps.geocode 'someaddress', (err, data) ->
      latLng = JSON.stringify data.results[0].geometry.location

      myModule.search latLng, item, searchResults

      return
  return
```

The `searchResults` function doesn't know about `res`, so how can I return data to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty common scenario. One option is to define `searchResults` inside of `exports.search`, but then `exports.search` might get unwieldy.

It doesn't make sense for `searchResults` to be defined in such a way that it uses `res` when `res` isn't an argument. But you may be reluctant to have functions with several arguments, which can lead to repetitive code when you have several callbacks that need to access the same state. One good option is to use a single hash to store that state. In this case, your code might look something like

```
searchResults = (err, data, {res}) ->
  ...

exports.search = (req, res) ->
  res.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  location = req.param 'location'
  item = req.param 'item'
  state = {req, res, location, item}

  geoC = googlemaps.geocode 'someaddress', (err, data) ->
      state.latLng = JSON.stringify data.results[0].geometry.location
      myModule.search state, searchResults
      return
  return
```

Notice that `myModule.search` now only takes the `state` hash and a callback; it then passes the `state` hash as the third argument to that callback (`searchResults`), which pulls `res` out of the hash using the destructuring argument syntax.

Answer (score 1):

A standard bind will do.

```
myModule.search latLng, item, searchResults.bind(null, res)

...

searchResults = (res, err, data)->
  res.write 'hello'
  console.log data
  console.log 'here'
  return
```